# How to type where the users cursor is

Tags: java

I am wanting to create an application that, when ran, types text at where the users current | typing cursor thing is. How can I check that a) the user is currently selecting a text box / the program can actually type in that spot, and b) how to type as the user.

Comment: What do you exactly need to do? Your question is unclear.

Comment: I basically just need to type as the user. In other words type on behalf of the user.

Comment: Need to type a text automatically if the text field is selected?

Comment: Kind of. I want the program to just type in the text as if it’s pressing the keys on a keyboard. I’ll ignore part A for now; I just need it to type in the text regardless of the effects and if the text actually shows up or whatever.

Comment: Check my answer if that is what you need. Or if you need to type character by character like showing what is typing, you can use Java [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class

Comment: The Robot class seems like what I need. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to set a text when the user selected a text field you will need to use the `focusGained` and `focusLost` events to see when the text field has been selected (gain focus), or it is deselected (lost focus).

Here is an example,

```
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final JTextField textField = new JTextField();

        textField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                // Your code here
                textField.setText("Sample Text");
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                // Your code here
                textField.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Or else you can type using Java [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class as follows,

```
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.Robot; 
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent; 

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Create an instance of Robot class 
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        final JTextField textField = new JTextField();

        textField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                // Your code here
                // Press keys using robot. A gap of 
                // of 500 mili seconds is added after 
                // every key press 
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H); 
                Thread.sleep(500); 
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E); 
                Thread.sleep(500); 
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L); 
                Thread.sleep(500); 
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L); 
                Thread.sleep(500); 
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O);
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                // Your code here
                textField.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```